# Appending new items with YUI Masonry Plugin

Tags: javascript, yui

According to the [docs here](http://yui-masonry.appspot.com/yuidoc/classes/Masonry.html#method_appended) I should be able to use

```
Y.one("#container").appended( newImages, function(){
   console.log("appended");
});
```

to add new items to my page, but I get an error saying `#container has no method 'appended'`.

If I try `Y.one("#container").masonry('appended', newImages);` it tells me that `#container` has no method 'masonry'

I do define masonry at the beginning of my function `var masonry = new Y.Masonry({ ...` so I'm confused on what I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing a bit the jQuery style with the YUI style. In jQuery calling the `$` function returns a `jQuery` object which has a lot of functions. But in YUI not all components are methods that can be called from a node query. In this case, Masonry is defined as a class from which all instances get certain methods like `appended()` or `reload()`. This means that your code should look like this:

```
var masonry = new Y.Masonry({ ... });
masonry.appended(newImages, function () {
  console.log("appended");
});
```

Comment: I recommend that you learn a bit of Object Oriented Programming. Eloquent JavaScript is probably a good book to start http://eloquentjavascript.net/. Then get the YUI3 Cookbook which will help you get up to speed with YUI in a breeze http://www.goer.org/YUI/